# Block scrolling on space press - Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

Symptom: when the user presses spacebar in **Google Chrome**, the page scrolls down a bit.

Why is it so important for me?

I develop a UNIX shell terminal simulator, in which users can enter text commands that include spaces. They just jump away on space press, and that's very annoying.

The alternate solutions are not what I really want:

- setting `position:fixed` on the terminal OR
- setting `overflow:hidden` on body
- removing the scrollbar and making a fake one using jQuery

I'm asking you for a possible better solution before I started putting effort into making an 'artificial' scrollbar on the right. Anyone who faced similar issue, what have you done?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661296/will-this-javascript-code-affect-other-keypress-events-too-by-disabling-one-key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using `event.preventDefault()`?

Something like:

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
     if (event.keyCode === 32 && event.target === document.body) {
         event.preventDefault();
     }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't heard of this before, now it's been implemented to the original js so the program works properly. thanks again